# Running game on separate thread does not stop the whole application from being closed - Unity on Android Studio

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-development

More or less the title. I call Application.quit() in Unity, and then in the onUnityPlayerQuitted method in my Android Studio app, I call this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Exit.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

However, this just closes the entire app. I've already got these statements in my androidmanifest.xml

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
android:process=":UnityPlayerActivity"
```

so I can't quite figure out why my app closes instead of going to the Exit activity as I called for it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by changing Application.quit to Application.Unload in Unity, and then having the activities run on different processes using the aforementioned xml tags.